# Fail back to AWS from Azure Site Recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, disaster-recovery, azure-site-recovery

We a implementing a solution where we are replicating EC2 Instances (VMs) from AWS to Azure using Azure Site Recovery. Please note we are not migrating to Azure and would only want to set up the replication from AWS to Azure for Disaster Recovery purposes.

As per the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/migrate-tutorial-aws-azure)  -

> AWS instances are treated like physical, on-premises computer.

Once we have setup everything like enabling replication, we should be able see the replicated VMs in Replicated Item on ASR. As per my understanding, when we run a failover, Azure VMs are created from replicated data in Azure storage.
Now when the primary AWS site is available again, what happens when we want to fail back to AWS.

As we are treating/considering AWS Instances as Physical, as per the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-faq#is-disaster-recovery-supported-for-physical-servers+)

> "Failback from Azure to an on-premises physical server isn't supported. You can only fail back to a VMware virtual machine”

Now the question is ‘Will we be able to Failback to the primary AWS site like the way we can fail back to VMware’?

Answer (score 0):

I answered your query @https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/51568/fail-back-to-aws-from-azure-site-recovery.html#answer-51979

Quoting from the link:

Only failover is supported for AWS machines. As you have already mentioned in quotes above, failback is not supported for AWS machines using Azure Site Recovery.

As long as Azure receives data from AWS machines, it will process it to make recovery points and those points would be available for you to failover to Azure enabling business continuity. In your case specifically, you can failover to Azure but going back to AWS will not be an option through Azure Site Recovery.